# Recent BBC coverage of SO, Jon Skeet (and UNIKONG)

Tags: discussion, unikong

I just saw this article about Jon Skeet's SO reputation (which also mentions UNIKONG) on the BBC News website: [Jon Skeet: The 'Chuck Norris' of programming](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-34596634)

Just a few days ago, this BBC [article](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20160325-the-names-that-break-computer-systems) about the problems of a woman whose surname is "Null" also had a link to an SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456438/how-do-i-correctly-pass-the-string-null-an-employees-proper-surname-to-a-so) about the problem of adding the name "Null" to a database.

Have the BBC only now discovered SO, or has there been coverage before? And is coverage in mainstream media a good or bad thing for SO?

Comment: My name occasionally breaks things, where's my news article? :p

Comment: Chuck Norris tried to stop Jon Skeet once. The aftermath of that epic battle was Windows Vista

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Well, you may have an apostrophe, but you're no Janice Keihanaikukauakahihulihe'ekahaunaele :-)

Comment: "to any programmer, it’s painfully easy to see why “Null” could cause problems [...] sometimes surprisingly difficult to solve" -> Not for any **competent** programmer. I'm guessing this is some sort of "clever" way to "check" if you're not doing SQL queries maybe (like some services disallowing quotes in passwords), or perhaps just plain stupid code with a very high wtf-value. You don't need to be Jon Skeet to do this correct...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker The SO question has 3781 upvotes, so apparently many people have struggled with similar issues.

Comment: @m69 That's a very specific bug for a very specific library. I suspect it just has a lot of upvotes because people share the link a lot (perhaps it's even on thedailywtf).

Comment: I'm not sure why I, as a layman, would really care if BBC has or hasn't covered Stack Overflow in the past...

Comment: I'd be worried if the BBC was talking about "bringing democracy" to SO... other than that, pity that Holly wasn't wearing a SO t-shirt.

Comment: "... is coverage in mainstream media a good or bad thing for SO?" We'll know when there is an upsurge of questions such as "my printer is not working, *halp!*" and "how do i sell my stuff on the web". I mean, way above the usual rate.

Comment: [Who](http://stackoverflow.com/users?search=chris+shaw) is that "Chris Shaw" who said "The site is like a Google answer site for computer problems"? StackOverflow is not a search engine, I don't understand the relation with Google.

Comment: "This week, he appeared in a Donkey Kong homage game produced by a fan on the site." - Huh? Is the SO team considered "a fan" of the site?

Comment: @Siguza You can't expect journalism to be an accurate representation of reality. That would be weird.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker. For a non-programmer, the reaction to hearing that the name Null causes problems is "huh? why?"; for any competent programmer, as the article says, the reaction is "Oh, yes, I can see why that would happen".

Comment: I'm changing my last name tomorrow.

Comment: Isn't it about time that the world now says **Chuck Norris: The 'Jon Skeet' of acting**?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

> Have the BBC only now discovered SO, or has there been coverage before? And is coverage in mainstream media a good or bad thing for SO?

The BBC hasn't just discovered SO, no. The journalist who wrote the piece (Emma Midgley) first got in touch with me back in October. I won't go into details of our conversation, but suffice it to say this isn't a "BBC-wide" awareness so much as a personal contact who knew about SO and knew that I was a local.

I don't know whether there's *any* relationship between the article about SO and the "Null" article.

Comment: Still - Congrats on the coverage Jon :) It's always nice to get recognition and it should help with the book.

Comment: Also related - Hacker News discussion https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11415705

Comment: The article mentioned you had an answered 32599 answers (yesterday) and today it's 32950! I suspect even this comment will be out-dated in a moments time!